# Shield UI CustomPointText

Tags: c#, asp.net, shieldui

I have a Shield UI Bar Chart and I would like to have a value from the data that is not shown in the graph itself. In this example I want to be able to access the data value for "strTest".

```
var dataHours = new List<HoursType>()
        {
            //This month
            new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billThisMonth / totalThisMonth * 100, 2), NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillThisMonth / totalThisMonth * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillThisMonth},
            //Last month
            new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billLastMonth / totalLastMonth * 100, 2), NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillLastMonth / totalLastMonth * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillLastMonth},
            //YTD
            new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billYTD / totalYTD * 100, 2), NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillYTD / totalYTD * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillYTD}
        };
        chtBillableNonBillable.DataSource = dataHours;
        chtBillableNonBillable.DataBind();
```

Here is the asp front end. I tried using point.strTest in the "CustomPointText" attribute but it doesn't get the data.

```
<shield:ShieldChart ID="chtBillableNonBillable" Width="100%" Height="400px" runat="server" CssClass="chart">
            <PrimaryHeader Text="Billable/Non-Billable Hours"></PrimaryHeader>
            <TooltipSettings CustomPointText="{point.strTest} / {point.y}"  >
            </TooltipSettings>
            <ExportOptions AllowExportToImage="true" AllowPrint="true" />
            <Axes>
                <shield:ChartAxisX CategoricalValues="Current Month, Last Month, YTD"></shield:ChartAxisX>
                <shield:ChartAxisY>
                    <Title Text="% of Hours"></Title>
                </shield:ChartAxisY>
            </Axes>
            <DataSeries>
                <shield:ChartBarSeries DataFieldY="Billable" CollectionAlias="Billable Hours" >
                </shield:ChartBarSeries>
                <shield:ChartBarSeries DataFieldY="NonBillable" CollectionAlias="Non-Billable Hours">
                </shield:ChartBarSeries>
            </DataSeries>
        </shield:ShieldChart>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show custom unbound value in the [BarChart](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/bar-chart/basic-usage) series tooltip you need to serialize the array with all strTest values on the client and to show the values for a custom point text in the tooltip. For example:

```
protected void chtBillableNonBillable_TakeDataSource(object sender, Shield.Web.UI.ChartTakeDataSourceEventArgs e)
```

{

```
var dataHours = new List<HoursType>()
{
    //This month
    new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billThisMonth / totalThisMonth * 100, 2),
        NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillThisMonth / totalThisMonth * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillThisMonth},
    //Last month
    new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billLastMonth / totalLastMonth * 100, 2), 
        NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillLastMonth / totalLastMonth * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillLastMonth},
    //YTD
    new HoursType() { Billable = Math.Round(billYTD / totalYTD * 100, 2), 
        NonBillable = Math.Round(nonBillYTD / totalYTD * 100, 2), strTest = nonBillYTD}
};
chtBillableNonBillable.DataSource = dataHours;

Page.RegisterArrayDeclaration("strTests", string.Join(",", dataHours.Select(s => s.strTest.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
```

}

```
<shield:ShieldChart ID="chtBillableNonBillable" Width="100%" Height="400px" OnTakeDataSource="chtBillableNonBillable_TakeDataSource" runat="server" CssClass="chart">
            <PrimaryHeader Text="Billable/Non-Billable Hours"></PrimaryHeader>
            <TooltipSettings PointClientCallbackFunction="PointClientCallbackFunction" CustomPointText="{point.strTest} / {point.y}">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PointClientCallbackFunction(point, chart) {

        return "strTest: " + strTests[point.x];
    }
</script>
```

Also more information about PointClientCallbackFunction you can find here:
[customPointText](http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/javascript.chart/api/tooltipSettings/customPointText)

Please give it try and let me know if the suggestion helps you. Also I am sending you a simple example which demonstrates it.

Comment: Thank you so much Katherine! This worked perfectly! This is exactly what I needed to get the data I wanted into the front end.